# What is the intent of the reference-books tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag [reference-books](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-books). Normally, I'd assume this is about, well, reference books (encyclopedias and alike). Yet, it does not seem to be used like this.

So, I wonder: What is the precise intent for this tag? At the moment it is used for question soliciting recommendations for books. If it is about this I would suggest a more telling name, like book-recommendations or perhaps literature-recommendations, not to limit it to books.

Comment: Don't we already have (reference-request) for this purpose?

Comment: On the one hand, yes. But, it is either very broad or actually not really applicable; to me a reference request is something quite specific, namely you ask for help to find a literature item to use as a reference in scholarly work (and things closely related to this). In either case I think there is room for an additional tag for more general literature recommendations.